# Ajax success showed incorrect form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to JavaScript.
I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="bto autorefund_success">...</div>
<div class="bto refund_error">...</div>
<div class="bto refund_sent">...</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bto{
  ...
  display: none;
  ...
}
```

I made an ajax request.

```
            $.ajax('/ticket', {
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: {
                    data: JSON.stringify(obj)
                },
                success: function (res) {
                    if ('refund' === res.action)    {$('.autorefund_success').fadeIn(); return;}
                    if ('cem'    === res.action)    {$('.refund_sent').fadeIn(); return;}
                    if ('error'  === res.action)    {$('.refund_error').fadeIn(); return;}                  
                }
            })
```

Received **res** object like this:

```
{
    action: "refund",
    err: "",
    ok: true
}
```

**action** can be: "refund", "cem", "error".

Only the **autorefund_success** form has to be shown. But **refund_sent** form is being shown instead.

I can't understand why CSS inline style

```
display: block;
```

is set to **autorefund_success** and **refund_sent** and not to **refund_error**.
The result I'm having is:

```
<div class="bto autorefund_success" style="display: block;">...</div>
<div class="bto refund_error">...</div>
<div class="bto refund_sent" style="display: block;">...</div>
```

Only **autorefund_success** must have display: block;.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: I suspect invalid html. (or html that doesn't match what you've provided) the html you provided looks fine

Comment: KevinB Thanks, I recheck html

Comment: Looks like your ajax code is getting called twice which is causing some issues. Can you please post the complete page source ?

Comment: Actually, html builds from several parts (templates). Full HTML page has about 2000 rows. You can see code. Unfortunately, you can't debug it. Page is for refund cinema's tickets. [link](https://multiplex.ua/ua/about)

Answer (score 0):

When you use fadeIn() method it will add inline CSS style (display : block) to your div

if your both div's are getting this style it means in your Ajax you are getting both **action: "refund"** and **action: "cem"**

Comment: Browser DevTool showed only one **/ticket** request. Thank you for you idea. It may be useful.